# java saying 'cannot find symbol' though method is declared in class

Tags: java, stack

I am writing a stack implementation program using linked list. In that, I have created a class `Node` which has all getters and setters and I have another class `Stack` which governs the stack operations. I am trying to show the stack elements, for which there's a separate function in class `Stack` as follows:

```
class Stack{
    Node start;
    int size;
    public void viewStack(){
        if(isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("Stack is Empty");
        } else {
            Node s = start;
            while(s.getNext()!=null){
                System.out.print(s.getData()+" ");
                s = s.getNext();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where, `isEmpty()` returns true or false according to the situation. The `getData()` is defined in class `node` as follows:

```
class Node{
    Node next;
    int data;
    public int getdata(){
        return data;
    }
}
```

the driver code is as follows:

```
public class StackDemo{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Stack st = new Stack();
        st.viewStack();
    }
}
```

I am getting error `cannot find symbol` and error is pointing to the `s.getData()` method. Why i am getting this error? help please.

Comment: "where, `viewStack()` returns true or false according to the situation" - No it doesn't, `viewStack()` is a `void` method, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Java is case-sensitive: `getData` and `getdata` are entirely separate identifiers.

Comment: getdata != getData. Voting to close for typo.

Comment: You need to start using some IDE unless you are in school.

Answer (score 2):

Because your method is `getdata` not `getData`

Answer (score 1):

Java is case-sensitive. The method you defined is `getdata` (with a lowercase d), while you're calling `getData` (with an upper case D). Fix the method declaration to `getData`, and you should be fine.